# Quotients of C[x,y] by two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking at quotients of $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$, but I'm getting confused when it's two elements.

For example: 
$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2)$, to me this just goes to $\mathbb{C}$ as $x$ and $y$ must be zero, but they it just seems a weird thing to quotient out by.

Similarly, I have $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x - \pi i , y)$, now would this go to $\mathbb{C}$ again or is it $\mathbb{C}[\pi]$ or is my logic just completely wrong.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{C}[\pi] = \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That's what I thought, so are they both the equal to the same thing, just different ways of doing them?

Comment: Note that $(x^2+y^2,x^2-y^2)=(x^2,y^2)$. Does it still seem like the quotient is $\Bbb{C}$ to you?

Comment: For the first ring $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2)$, I think you will get $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$. In any case it cannot be a field because the ideal is not prime.

Comment: For the first one, observe that $(x^2+y^2, x^2-y^2)=(x^2,y^2)$, and for the second one use $(A/I)/(J/I) \simeq A/J$ ([third isomorphism theorem for rings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems)).

Comment: I don't understand why $(x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2) = (x^2, y^2)$

Comment: @user901823 Try adding and subtracting $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$.

Comment: ok so because $x^2 + y^2$ and  $x^2 - y^2$ goes to zero any linear combination of them do?

Edit: To the zero element of the ring

Comment: You need to show the following: if $I=(a_1, \cdots , a_n)$ and $J=(b_1, \cdots ,b_m)$ are two ideals in a commutative ring with identity, and if $a_i \in J$ for $1\leq i \leq n$ and $b_i \in I$ for $1\leq i \leq m$, then $I=J$. The above one is very special (and far more easier) case of this, but it never hurts to prove the general result.

Comment: @user901823 Sure, if by "linear" combination, you mean things of the form $a(x,y) (x^2+y^2) + b(x,y) (x^2-y^2)$ with $a(x,y), b(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (so you could certainly take $a$ and $b$ to be constants).  As Krish suggests, I think the easiest way of seeing it is proving $(x^2+y^2, x^2-y^2) = (x^2, y^2)$.  This can be done by showing $x^2, y^2 \in (x^2+y^2, x^2-y^2)$ and $x^2+y^2, x^2-y^2 \in (x^2, y^2)$.

Comment: That makes sense, so then any element in the first quotient is just a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ with degree of $x$ and $y$ less that 2?

Answer (score 3):

The quotient $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2)$ is a bunch of equivalence classes, with relations $[x^2 + y^2] \cong [0]$ and $[x^2 - y^2] \cong [0]$.  (That's normally too much writing, so one usually writes $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ and $x^2 - y^2 = 0$.)

These give 
$$  [2x^2] \cong [x^2 + y^2] + [x^2 - y^2] \cong [0] + [0] \cong 0  $$ 
and 
$$  [2y^2] \cong [x^2 + y^2] - [x^2 - y^2] \cong [0] - [0] \cong 0  \text{.}  $$
Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, $[x^2] = \frac{1}{2}[2x^2] = [0]$ and $[y^2] = \frac{1}{2}[2y^2] = [0]$.  If you trace through what we have done, we have applied an invertible $\mathbb{C}$-linear (so certainly $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-linear) transformation to the generators, $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 - y^2$ to produce a new set of generators $x^2$ and $y^2$.  This means $I = (x^2 + y^2, x^2 - y^2) = (x^2, y^2)$.

Since no $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$-linear combination of $x^2$ and $y^2$ can ever produce a term linear in $y$ or in $x$, $[x]$ and $[y]$ survive as equivalence classes distinct from $[0]$ in $R/I$.  Similarly, $[xy] \neq [0]$ in $R/I$.  Since any term with more $x$s or $y$s is in the ideal, $I$, the resulting polynomial ring is generated by the surviving monomials.
$$  R \cong \mathbb{C} 1 \oplus \mathbb{C} x \oplus \mathbb{C} y \oplus \mathbb{C} xy \cong \mathbb{C}^4  \text{.}  $$

In your second ring, the second generator of the ideal turns all powers of $y$ into $0$ and the first generator turns all powers of $x$ into elements of $\mathbb{C}$.  Thus every monomial in $x$ and $y$ is turned into an element of $\mathbb{C}$ in the quotient.  The resulting ring is therefore isomorphic to just $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Okay, I think I've got it, my issue was that with $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ I thought that meant $x^2 = -y^2$ therefore $x = y = 0$, but does it actually only mean $x^2 = 0 = y^2$?

Comment: @user901823 : Being *very* careful, it actually only means $x^2 = -y^2$, or what is the same, $-x^2 = y^2$.  Perhaps another way to think of this : in $(\mathbb{C}[x])[y]$ any $y^2$ can be replaced by $-x^2$ (but this doesn't mean we can replace plain $y$s).

Comment: Ah I think that makes sense, so if I were to quotient out by only $(x^2 + y^2)$ I would have $x^2 = - y^2$ so the elements of the quotient would have y with maximum power 1 and x with any power? If that makes sense, so $a + bx + cy + dx^2 + eyx^2  + x^3$....

Comment: @user901823 : I agree.

Comment: $R$ is definitely NOT isomorphic to $\mathbb C^4$ as rings! (Count how many idempotents they have.) However they are isomorphic as $\mathbb C$-vector spaces.